# How to scrape a string from the div tag using Selenium and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I have source code like the code below.  I'm trying to scrape out the '11 tigers' string.  I'm new to xpath, can anyone suggest how to get it using selenium or beatiful soup?  I'm thinking `driver.find_element_by_xpath` or `soup.find_all`.

source:

```
<div class="count-box fixed_when_handheld s-vgLeft0_5 s-vgPullBottom1 s-vgRight0_5 u-colorGray6 u-fontSize18 u-fontWeight200" style="display: block;">
<div class="label-container u-floatLeft">11 tigers</div>
<div class="u-floatRight">
<div class="hide_when_tablet hide_when_desktop s-vgLeft0_5 s-vgRight0_5 u-textAlignCenter">
<div class="js-show-handheld-filters c-button c-button--md c-button--blue s-vgRight1">
Filter
</div>
<div class="js-save-handheld-filters c-button c-button--md c-button--transparent">
Save
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cb"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use same `.count-box .label-container` css selector for both BS and Selenium.

BS:

```
page = BeautifulSoup(yourhtml, "html.parser")
# if you need first one
label = page.select_one(".count-box .label-container").text
# if you need all
labels = page.select(".count-box .label-container")
for label in labels:
    print(label.text)
```

Selenium:

```
labels = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".count-box .label-container") 
for label in labels:
    print(label.text)
```

Comment: Thank  you, I tried the Selenium solution it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Variant of the answer given by Sers.

```
page = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "lxml")

# first one
label = page.find('div',{'class':'count-box label-container')).text

# for all
labels = page.find('div',{'class':'count-box label-container'))
for label in labels:
    print(label.text)
```

Use `lxml` parser as it's faster. You need to install it explicitly via `pip install lxml`

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **11 tigers** you can use either of the following solution:

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  my_text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.count-box>div.label-container.u-floatLeft").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  my_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'count-box')]/div[@class='label-container u-floatLeft']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```